# Transforming a Mat matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, computer-vision

I am using C++ and opencv. I have to obtain a transformation matrix when I multiply a matrix,A, with another matrix,B. But matrix B needs to change before multiplying it to A. If B is a 2x3 matrix, it needs to be changed to a 3x3 with the first 2 rows containing the same elements as the original B matrix,but with the last row having all 1's. More simple put,I need to add a last row of 1's to the original B matrix. I want to know whether I can achieve this with any specific Mat matrix operation. Thankyou

Comment: On its own,the matrix elements of the original Mat object are being displayed on only one row(See this http://i.imgur.com/JFb49of.jpg, where (55,118) is one coordinate) I tried adding the last row of 1's as you guys suggested but it's not working. Either im not looking hard enough but I am not able to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [Mat::push_back](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-push-back) which will adds elements to the bottom of the matrix.

For example

```
          Mat A = (Mat_<uchar>(3,4) << 1, 2,  3,  4,\
                                       5, 6,  7,  8,\
                                       9, 10, 11, 12);  // 3X4  matrix.

          Mat B = (Mat_<uchar>(1,4) << 13, 14,  15,  16); // 1X4 matrix

          A.push_back(B); // Now A become 4X4 matrix
```

Comment: Neat. I am so used to the Python OpenCV API that I did not know this existed. :)

Comment: is your code in python? ok,I do not explicitly input the original matrix but when I add the Mat B part with 1's in bracket,I get this error http://i.imgur.com/Mff4Q6z.jpg

Comment: @Steph No this pure C++ code. And make sure that number of columns for both Mat should be equal, that is if A is 2X3 order Mat then B should be NX3 where N>0.

Answer (score 1):

A straight forward way, but probably not the fastest or prettiest

```
Mat B_new(3,3,CV_32F);
B_new.row(0) = B.row(0);
B_new.row(1) = B.row(1);
B_new.row(2) = Mat::ones(1,3,CV_32F);
```

You should take a look at the [`Mat` type documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat)

Comment: thanks but I get the following error http://i.imgur.com/o6PLnQq.jpg My original matrix is a 2x6 one